# Data Matrix generator for Android

Tags: java, android, barcode

I know the `zxing` library is the best library for generating barcodes, but they do not support Data Matrix barcodes.

I found a few alternatives, but none suite my needs:

- I found a few which are commercial and pretty expensive
- I found `barcode4j`, which is good, but doesn't seem to work on Android.

More on barcode4j: http://barcode4j.sourceforge.net/2.1/

It lists several options on generating the barcode(SAXON, Servlet, etc), none of which I think are possible with a standard android application. I may be wrong, but is it possible work with any of these solutions:

- SAXON
- Servlet
- Xalan
- FOP
- Ant
- JavaBean

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the demo that comes with the download you should be able to make the "embedding" example work in Android.

Comment: It still uses the GWT package